# HadoopConfiguration Properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, properties

In my Spark code, I have to set ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY in HadoopConfiguration to access AWS-S3. Over the internet, I found multiple ways to set these properties.

For e.g.

**Style #1**,

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.access.key", AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_KEY)
```

**Style #2**,

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", AWS_SECRET_KEY)
```

In the above syntax, Style #1 (**fs.s3n.access.key**) is **NOT** working while Style #2 (**fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId**) is working fine.
I would like to know does Style #1 is specific to any hadoop version or is it not supported in hadoop configuration?

Where can I found all the possible HadoopConfiguration properties, related to spark, aws, hive, s3 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`access.key` and `secret.key` are used in `s3a` connector. AFAIR, `s3n` scheme always used `awsAccessKeyId/awsSecretAccessKey` style.

For configuration reference go to the [official hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) or [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3native/S3NativeFileSystemConfigKeys.java#L34), that's the best way to verify configuration parameters names.